# Shark cipher SBox

Tags: symmetric, s-boxes

In the literature, I can’t find the S-Box component of SHARK block cipher. I appreciate if anyone help to find the elements of the S-Box of this cipher.

Comment: Try http://ftp.esat.kuleuven.ac.be/cosic/rijmen/shark/

Comment: In this file, the SBox has 256 elements, but shark has only 64 elements. It’s confusing 

Comment: Shark is a 64-bit block cipher. It subdivides the block into 8 sub-blocks of 8 bits. It uses 8-bit in, 8-bit out S-boxes with thus $2^8=256$ entries each 8 bits. See the [defining paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-60865-6_47.pdf#page=3) to clear up any confusion.